# myUnitTest System.DmlException: Update failed

Tags: force.com, deployment

I have created Apex Class, followed by test class and a vf page related to Apex Class. Now every time I am deploying I am getting the error message. Please suggest and let me know how to make the deployment successful.

> ## Deploy Results:    File Name:    classes/ResourceBillRate.cls    Full Name:  ResourceBillRate    Action:  UPDATED    Result:  SUCCESS
>
> Problem: n/a
>
> File Name:    classes/testResourceBillRate.cls    Full Name: 
>   testResourceBillRate    Action:  UPDATED    Result:  SUCCESS
>   Problem: n/a
>
> File Name:    package.xml    Full Name:  package.xml    Action: 
>   UPDATED    Result:  SUCCESS    Problem: n/a
>
> File Name:    pages/VF_ResrouceBillRate.page    Full Name: 
>   VF_ResrouceBillRate    Action:  UPDATED    Result:  SUCCESS
>   Problem: n/a
>
> ## Test Results:
>
> **Run Failures:**   testResourceBillRate.myUnitTest System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id
>   a0I9000000FllpCEAR; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY,
>   trg_CalculateHours: execution of BeforeUpdate
>
> caused by: System.QueryException: Non-selective query against large
>   object type (more than 100000 rows). Consider an indexed filter or
>   contact salesforce.com about custom indexing. Even if a field is
>   indexed a filter might still not be selective when:
>   1. The filter value includes null (for instance binding with a list that contains null)
>   2. Data skew exists whereby the number of matching rows is very large (for instance, filtering for a particular foreign key value that
>   occurs many times)
>
> Trigger.trg_CalculateHours: line 37, column 1: []
>   testResourceBillRate.myUnitTest1 System.DmlException: Update failed.
>   First exception on row 0 with id a0I9000000FllpDEAR; first error:
>   CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, trg_CalculateHours: execution of
>   BeforeUpdate
>
> caused by: System.QueryException: Non-selective query against large
>   object type (more than 100000 rows). Consider an indexed filter or
>   contact salesforce.com about custom indexing. Even if a field is
>   indexed a filter might still not be selective when:
>   1. The filter value includes null (for instance binding with a list that contains null)
>   2. Data skew exists whereby the number of matching rows is very large (for instance, filtering for a particular foreign key value that
>   occurs many times)
>
> Trigger.trg_CalculateHours: line 37, column 1: []
>
> testTrgAgencyInfoUpdate.myUnitTest System.DmlException: Insert
>   failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
>   FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Vendor selected above does not
>   belongs to this Project.: [Project_ID__c]
>
> testTrgUpdateCost.myUnitTest System.DmlException: Insert failed.
>   First exception on row 0; first error:
>   FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Vendor selected above does not
>   belongs to this Project.: [Project_ID__c]
>
> testTrgUpdateCost.myUnitTest2 System.DmlException: Insert failed.
>   First exception on row 0; first error:
>   FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Vendor selected above does not
>   belongs to this Project.: [Project_ID__c]
>
> testTrgUpdateCost.myUnitTest44 System.DmlException: Insert failed.
>   First exception on row 0; first error:
>   FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Vendor selected above does not
>   belongs to this Project.: [Project_ID__c]
>
> Average test coverage across all Apex Classes and Triggers is 73%,
>   at least 75% test coverage is required.

---

**ResourceBillRate.cls**

```
public with sharing class ResourceBillRate{

    /* Properties and public variables*/
    public ID StartsheetID;
    Public Date pTo;
    Public Date pFrom;
    public boolean bIsGenerated;
    List<Timecard_Entries__c> tCard = new List<Timecard_Entries__c>();
    List<Resource_Bill_Rate__c> rscBillRate = new List<Resource_Bill_Rate__c>();
    List<Billing_Repository__c> rscAgencyRate = new List<Billing_Repository__c>();
    public List<wrapperInvoiceDetails> lstWrpInvDtl{get;set;}
    String parentId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    string sRecordType;
    RecordType objRT = new RecordType();
    public Generate_Invoice__c gInvoice{get;set;} 
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController;
    public boolean bIsDispAmount{get;set;}
    public decimal dTotalAmount{get;set;}
    public string sBillingRate{get;set;}
    public integer StandardHours;


    public ResourceBillRate(ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController){
        this.standardController = standardController;
    }    
    public ResourceBillRate(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
            system.debug('*********************************ResourceBillRateCalled : ');
      lstWrpInvDtl = new List<wrapperInvoiceDetails>();
      gInvoice = [select RecordType.Name,Project_ID__c,Project_ID__r.Billing_Rate__c,Period_From__c,Period_To__c,Invoice_Generated__c,Consultant__c from Generate_Invoice__c where id=:parentId];

      bIsGenerated = gInvoice.Invoice_Generated__c ;
      StartsheetID = gInvoice.Project_ID__c;
      pFrom = gInvoice.Period_From__c;
      pTo = gInvoice.Period_To__c;
      sRecordType = gInvoice.RecordType.Name;
      sBillingRate = gInvoice.Project_ID__r.Billing_Rate__c;


      system.debug('*********************************gInvoice : '+gInvoice);
      system.debug('*********************************StartsheetID : '+StartsheetID);
      //RscBillRate();
    }

    public void RscBillRate()
    {
       /*rscBillRate = [Select Name,Bill_Rate__c,Bill_Type__c,Project_ID__r.Name,Resource_Name__c,Total_Billable_Hours__c,
        fml_Period_From__c,Period_From_new__c,Period_To__c from Resource_Bill_Rate__c where 
        Project_ID__c=:StartsheetID and Period_From_new__c>=:pFrom and Period_To__c<=:pTo
        order by createdDate Asc]; */

        List<TimeCard__c> lstTC = [Select id ,Project_ID__c,Period_From__c,Period_To__c from TimeCard__c where Project_ID__c =:StartsheetID ]; 


        tCard = [SELECT Date__c,Hours__c,Project_ID__c, Invoice_Generated__c, TimeCard__c FROM Timecard_Entries__c WHERE Project_ID__c
                 =:StartsheetID and Date__c >=:pFrom and Date__c <=:pTo];                

       if(sRecordType == 'Agency Invoice')
       {
         AgencyBilling(lstTC);
       }
       if(sRecordType == 'Consulting Invoice')
       {                    
         ConsultingBilling(lstTC);
       }


  }

  public void MonthlyStandardHours()
  {
    date ob = date.today();
    integer iYear = ob.year();
    integer iMonth = ob.month();
    List<US_Calender_Yearly__c>lstY = [Select id,Standard_Hours__c from US_Calender_Yearly__c where Month_Number__c =:iMonth and US_Calender_Yearly__r.Year__c =:iYear];
    StandardHours = integer.valueof(lstY[0].Standard_Hours__c);
  }

  private void AgencyBilling(List<TimeCard__c> lstTC)
  {

    MonthlyStandardHours();

    //lstWrpInvDtl = new List<wrapperInvoiceDetails>();
    if(sBillingRate == 'Monthly' && bIsGenerated == false)
      {
        bIsDispAmount = true;
      }
      else
      {
         bIsDispAmount = false;
      }

      rscAgencyRate  = [SELECT To_Date__c,From_Date__c,Total_Billable_Hours__c,Customer_Billing__r.Startsheet__r.Resource__r.Name,Customer_Billing__r.Startsheet__r.Billing_Rate__c,Agency_Rate_Hour__c, Agency_Rate_Month__c, Name,Current_Hourly_Billing_Rate__c,Current_Monthly_Billing_Rate__c,Customer_Billing__c,Effective_Bill_Date__c, Employee_Annual_Salary__c, GP_Rate__c, Hourly_Cost__c,Id  
                      FROM Billing_Repository__c where Customer_Billing__r.Startsheet__c =:StartsheetID and From_Date__c >=: pFrom 
                      order by createdDate Asc];

    system.debug('++++++tCard+++++++'+tCard.size());

     for(integer i=0;i<rscAgencyRate.size();i++)
     {
       rscAgencyRate[i].Total_Billable_Hours__c = 0;
       for(integer k=0;k<tCard.size();k++)
       {
         if(tCard[k].Date__c <= rscAgencyRate[i].To_Date__c && tCard[k].Date__c>=rscAgencyRate[i].From_Date__c)
         {
           rscAgencyRate[i].Total_Billable_Hours__c = rscAgencyRate[i].Total_Billable_Hours__c + tCard[k].Hours__c ;
         }
       }

       //rscAgencyRate[i].From_Date__c = lstTC[0].Period_From__c;
       //rscAgencyRate[i].To_Date__c = lstTC[0].Period_To__c ;
      } 
       system.debug('++++++rscAgencyRate+++++++'+rscAgencyRate);

       if(bIsGenerated)
       {
         system.debug('++++++bIsGenerated+++++++'+bIsGenerated);
         List<Invoice_Details__c> lstInvDtls = [Select id,Amount__c,From__c,Generate_Invoice__c,Hours__c,Rate__c,Rate_Type__c,Resource_Name__c,To_Date__c from Invoice_Details__c where Generate_Invoice__c =: parentId];

           List<Invoice_Details__c> lstInvDtlsTest = [Select id,Amount__c,From__c,Generate_Invoice__c,Hours__c,Rate__c,Rate_Type__c,Resource_Name__c,To_Date__c from Invoice_Details__c ];

         system.debug('parent id >'+parentId);

           system.debug('+++lstInvDtlsTest >+++'+ lstInvDtlsTest );

         if(lstInvDtls.size()<=0)
         {
           //Save record in invoice detail
           List<Invoice_Details__c> lstInsrtInvDtl = new List<Invoice_Details__c>();

           system.debug('++++++rscAgencyRate.size()+++++++'+rscAgencyRate.size());
           for(integer i=0;i<rscAgencyRate.size();i++)
           {
             wrapperInvoiceDetails obj = new wrapperInvoiceDetails(rscAgencyRate[i]);
             lstWrpInvDtl.add(obj);

             if(sBillingRate == 'Monthly')
             {
                 lstWrpInvDtl[i].Amount = (lstWrpInvDtl[i].Rate/StandardHours)* lstWrpInvDtl[i].Hours;
             }
             if(sBillingRate == 'Hourly')
             {
               lstWrpInvDtl[i].Amount = lstWrpInvDtl[i].Rate * lstWrpInvDtl[i].Hours ;
             }  

             Invoice_Details__c objInv = new Invoice_Details__c();
             objInv.Generate_Invoice__c = parentId ;
             objInv.Amount__c = obj.Amount;
             objInv.Hours__c = obj.Hours;
             objInv.Rate__c = obj.Rate;
             objInv.Rate_Type__c = obj.RateType;
             objInv.To_Date__c = obj.ToDate;
             objInv.From__c = obj.FromDate;
             objInv.Resource_Name__c = obj.ResourceName ;
             lstInsrtInvDtl.add(objInv);
           }

           system.debug('++++++lstInsrtInvDtl+++++++'+lstInsrtInvDtl);
           insert lstInsrtInvDtl;
         }
         else
         {
           system.debug('++++++lstInvDtls.size()+++++++'+lstInvDtls.size());
           //get data from invoice details
           for(integer i=0;i<lstInvDtls.size();i++)
           {
             wrapperInvoiceDetails obj = new wrapperInvoiceDetails(lstInvDtls[i]);
             lstWrpInvDtl.add(obj);
           }
         } 
       }
       else
       { 
          system.debug('++++++rscAgencyRate.size()+++++++'+rscAgencyRate.size()); 
           for(integer i=0;i<rscAgencyRate.size();i++)
           {
              wrapperInvoiceDetails obj = new wrapperInvoiceDetails(rscAgencyRate[i]);
              lstWrpInvDtl.add(obj);

              system.debug('++++++sBillingRate+++++++'+sBillingRate); 
              if(sBillingRate == 'Monthly')
              {
               //lstWrpInvDtl[0].Amount = lstWrpInvDtl[0].Amount__c;
               lstWrpInvDtl[i].Amount = (lstWrpInvDtl[i].Rate/StandardHours)* lstWrpInvDtl[i].Hours;
               system.debug('++++++lstWrpInvDtl[i].Amount+++++++'+lstWrpInvDtl[i].Amount); 
              }
              if(sBillingRate == 'Hourly')
              {
                lstWrpInvDtl[i].Amount = lstWrpInvDtl[i].Rate * lstWrpInvDtl[i].Hours ;
                system.debug('++++++lstWrpInvDtl[i].Amount+++++++'+lstWrpInvDtl[i].Amount); 
                system.debug('++++++lstWrpInvDtl[i].Hours+++++++'+lstWrpInvDtl[i].Hours); 
              }  
            }
       } 

     //Fill Total Amount
     dTotalAmount = lstWrpInvDtl[0].Amount ;    

  }

  public void UpdateAgencyTotalAmount()
  {

    lstWrpInvDtl[0].Amount = dTotalAmount ;
    List<Invoice_Details__c> lstInvDtls = [Select id from Invoice_Details__c where Generate_Invoice__c =: parentId];
    List<Invoice_Details__c>lstInsrtInvDtl2 = new List<Invoice_Details__c>();
    for(integer i=0;i<lstWrpInvDtl.size();i++)
    {
     //wrapperInvoiceDetails obj = new wrapperInvoiceDetails(rscBillRate[i]);
     //lstWrpInvDtl.add(obj);

     Invoice_Details__c objInv = new Invoice_Details__c();
     objInv.id = lstInvDtls[0].id;
     objInv.Generate_Invoice__c = parentId ;
     objInv.Amount__c = dTotalAmount ;
     objInv.Hours__c = lstWrpInvDtl[0].Hours;
     objInv.Rate__c = lstWrpInvDtl[0].Rate;
     objInv.Rate_Type__c = lstWrpInvDtl[0].RateType;
     objInv.To_Date__c = lstWrpInvDtl[0].ToDate;
     objInv.From__c = lstWrpInvDtl[0].FromDate;
     objInv.Resource_Name__c = lstWrpInvDtl[0].ResourceName ;
     lstInsrtInvDtl2.add(objInv);
    }

    update lstInsrtInvDtl2;

  }

  private void ConsultingBilling(List<TimeCard__c> lstTC)
  {
     MonthlyStandardHours();

     rscBillRate = [Select Resource__r.Name,Name,Bill_Rate__c,Bill_Type_New__c,Project_ID__r.Name,Resource_Name__c,Total_Billable_Hours__c,
                       fml_Period_From__c,Period_From_new__c,Period_To__c,Project_ID__r.Billing_Rate__c,Project_ID__r.Standard_Hours__c from Resource_Bill_Rate__c where 
                       Project_ID__c=:StartsheetID and Period_From_new__c<=:pFrom and  Period_To__c >=:pTo
                       order by createdDate Asc];

     for(integer i=0;i<rscBillRate.size();i++)
     {
       system.debug('++++++rscBillRate+++++++'+rscBillRate);

       if(rscBillRate[i].Project_ID__r.Billing_Rate__c == 'Monthly')
       {
         system.debug('++++++rscBillRate 9+++++++'+rscBillRate[i].Project_ID__r.Billing_Rate__c);
         system.debug('++++++rscBillRate[i].Bill_Rate__c 11+++++++'+rscBillRate[i].Bill_Rate__c);
         system.debug('++++++rscBillRate[i].Project_ID__r.Standard_Hours__c 12+++++++'+rscBillRate[i].Project_ID__r.Standard_Hours__c);
         system.debug('++++++rscBillRate[i].Total_Billable_Hours__c 13+++++++'+rscBillRate[i].Total_Billable_Hours__c);



         //StandardHours
         //rscBillRate[i].Bill_Rate__c = (rscBillRate[i].Bill_Rate__c /rscBillRate[i].Project_ID__r.Standard_Hours__c)*rscBillRate[i].Total_Billable_Hours__c;
         //rscBillRate[i].Bill_Rate__c = (rscBillRate[i].Bill_Rate__c /StandardHours)*rscBillRate[i].Total_Billable_Hours__c;
         system.debug('++++++rscBillRate 3+++++++'+rscBillRate[i].Project_ID__r.Billing_Rate__c);
       }
       rscBillRate[i].Total_Billable_Hours__c = 0;
       for(integer k=0;k<tCard.size();k++)
       {
         if(tCard[k].Date__c <= rscBillRate[i].Period_To__c && tCard[k].Date__c>=rscBillRate[i].Period_From_new__c)
         {
           rscBillRate[i].Total_Billable_Hours__c = rscBillRate[i].Total_Billable_Hours__c + tCard[k].Hours__c ;
         }
       }
        system.debug('++++++rscBillRate 4+++++++'+rscBillRate[i]);
       rscBillRate[i].Period_From_new__c = lstTC[0].Period_From__c;
       rscBillRate[i].Period_To__c = lstTC[0].Period_To__c ;
      }  
       system.debug('++++++rscBillRate 1+++++++'+rscBillRate);
       if(bIsGenerated)
       {
         List<Invoice_Details__c> lstInvDtls = [Select id,Amount__c,From__c,Generate_Invoice__c,Hours__c,Rate__c,Rate_Type__c,Resource_Name__c,To_Date__c from Invoice_Details__c where Generate_Invoice__c =: parentId];
          system.debug('++++++lstInvDtls+++++++'+lstInvDtls);
            system.debug('++++++parentId+++++++'+parentId);

         if(lstInvDtls.size()<=0)
         {
           //Save record in invoice detail
           List<Invoice_Details__c> lstInsrtInvDtl = new List<Invoice_Details__c>();

           for(integer i=0;i<rscBillRate.size();i++)
           {
             wrapperInvoiceDetails obj = new wrapperInvoiceDetails(rscBillRate[i]);
             lstWrpInvDtl.add(obj);

             Invoice_Details__c objInv = new Invoice_Details__c();
             objInv.Generate_Invoice__c = parentId ;
             objInv.Amount__c = obj.Amount;
             objInv.Hours__c = obj.Hours;
             objInv.Rate__c = obj.Rate;
             objInv.Rate_Type__c = obj.RateType;
             objInv.To_Date__c = obj.ToDate;
             objInv.From__c = obj.FromDate;
             objInv.Resource_Name__c = obj.ResourceName ;
             lstInsrtInvDtl.add(objInv);
           }

           system.debug('++++++lstInsrtInvDtl+++++++'+lstInsrtInvDtl);
           insert lstInsrtInvDtl;
         }
         else
         {
           //get data from invoice details
           for(integer i=0;i<lstInvDtls.size();i++)
           {
             wrapperInvoiceDetails obj = new wrapperInvoiceDetails(lstInvDtls[i]);
             lstWrpInvDtl.add(obj);
           }
         } 
       }
       else
       { 
           for(integer i=0;i<rscBillRate.size();i++)
           {
             wrapperInvoiceDetails obj = new wrapperInvoiceDetails(rscBillRate[i]);
             lstWrpInvDtl.add(obj);
           }
          system.debug('++++++sBillingRate+++++++'+sBillingRate); 
         if(sBillingRate == 'Monthly')
         {
           //lstWrpInvDtl[0].Amount = lstWrpInvDtl[0].Amount__c;
          lstWrpInvDtl[0].Amount = (lstWrpInvDtl[0].Rate/StandardHours)* lstWrpInvDtl[0].Hours;
          system.debug('++++++lstWrpInvDtl[0].Amount+++++++'+lstWrpInvDtl[0].Amount); 
         }
         if(sBillingRate == 'Hourly')
         {
           lstWrpInvDtl[0].Amount = lstWrpInvDtl[0].Rate * lstWrpInvDtl[0].Hours ;
           system.debug('++++++lstWrpInvDtl[0].Amount+++++++'+lstWrpInvDtl[0].Amount); 
         }  
       }                
  }


  public class wrapperInvoiceDetails
  {
    public Id InvDtlId{get;set;}
    public boolean isChecked{get;set;}
    public Id ResourceId{get;set;}
    public string ResourceName{get;set;}
    public decimal Hours{get;set;}
    public decimal Rate{get;set;}
    public string RateType{get;set;}
    public decimal Amount{get;set;}

    public date ToDate{get;set;}
    public date FromDate{get;set;}

    public wrapperInvoiceDetails()
    {}
    public wrapperInvoiceDetails(Resource_Bill_Rate__c obj)
    {

      //ResourceId = obj.Resource__c;
      ResourceName = obj.Resource__r.Name;
      Hours = obj.Total_Billable_Hours__c;
      Rate = obj.Bill_Rate__c;
      RateType = obj.Bill_Type_New__c;
      //Amount = obj.Bill_Rate__c * obj.Total_Billable_Hours__c;
      Amount = 0;

      ToDate = obj.Period_To__c ;
      FromDate = obj.Period_From_new__c ; 
    }
    public wrapperInvoiceDetails(Invoice_Details__c obj)
    {
      InvDtlId = obj.id;
      //ResourceId = obj.Resource__c;
      ResourceName = obj.Resource_Name__c;
      Hours = obj.Hours__c;
      Rate = obj.Rate__c;
      RateType = obj.Rate_Type__c;
      Amount = obj.Amount__c;

      ToDate = obj.To_Date__c;
      FromDate = obj.From__c;
    }
    public wrapperInvoiceDetails(Billing_Repository__c obj)
    {
      //ResourceId = obj.Resource__c;
      system.debug('++++++obj 1+++++'+obj);
      if(obj.Customer_Billing__r != null)
      {
        ResourceName = obj.Customer_Billing__r.Startsheet__r.Resource__r.Name;
        system.debug('++++++obj 2+++++'+obj);
      }
      else
      {
        ResourceName ='';
        system.debug('++++++obj 3+++++'+obj);
      }

      Hours = obj.Total_Billable_Hours__c ;
      if(obj.Customer_Billing__r !=null)
      {
         system.debug('++++++obj 4+++++'+obj.Customer_Billing__r.Startsheet__r.Billing_Rate__c);
          if(obj.Customer_Billing__r.Startsheet__r.Billing_Rate__c == 'Hourly')
             Rate = obj.Agency_Rate_Hour__c;
          else
             Rate = obj.Agency_Rate_Month__c;

        RateType = obj.Customer_Billing__r.Startsheet__r.Billing_Rate__c;  
        system.debug('++++++obj 5+++++'+obj.Agency_Rate_Hour__c);   
      }
      else
      {
        Rate =0;
        RateType ='';
        system.debug('++++++obj 6+++++'+obj);
      }


      //Amount = obj.Bill_Rate__c * obj.Total_Billable_Hours__c;
      //Amount = Rate 

      ToDate = obj.To_Date__c;
      FromDate = obj.From_Date__c;
    }

  }   

}
```

---

**Test Class - For test class - please download the same. When I pasted the class it blocked me due to space issues. Please download the class from below link**.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/odol33468mx7hbw/ResourceTestBill.txt

---

**Trigger For Trg_CalculateHours**

```
trigger trg_CalculateHours on Resource_Bill_Rate__c (before update)
{
    Public Decimal TotalBillableHours = 0;
    public ID ProjectID;
    public integer i=0;
    public Date pFrom;
    public Date pTo;
    Set<Id> rscBillrt = new Set<Id>();
    List<Resource_Bill_Rate__c> lstRsc = new List<Resource_Bill_Rate__c>();
    List<Timecard_Entries__c> tCard = new List<Timecard_Entries__c>();
    List<Timecard_Entries__c> tCard2 = new List<Timecard_Entries__c>();

for(Resource_Bill_Rate__c rs : trigger.new)
    {
        if(rs.Trigger_to_Calculate_Hours__c==TRUE)
        rscBillrt.add(rs.Id);
    }

lstRsc = [Select Period_From_new__c,Period_To__c,Project_ID__c from Resource_Bill_Rate__c where Id in:rscBillrt];

    system.debug('*********************lstRsc : '+lstRsc); 

    for(Resource_Bill_Rate__c r: lstRsc)
    {
        ProjectID = r.Project_ID__c;
        pFrom = r.Period_From_new__c;
        pTo = r.Period_To__c;
    }
        system.debug('*********************ProjectID : '+ProjectID); 
        system.debug('*********************pFrom : '+pFrom); 
        system.debug('*********************pTo : '+pTo);                       

        tCard = [SELECT Hours__c,Project_ID__c, Invoice_Generated__c, TimeCard__c FROM Timecard_Entries__c WHERE Project_ID__c
            =:ProjectID and Date__c >=:pFrom and Date__c <=:pTo];
    tCard2 = [SELECT Hours__c,Project_ID__c, Invoice_Generated__c, TimeCard__c FROM Timecard_Entries__c ];

    system.debug('*********************tCard : '+tCard.size());
    system.debug('*********************tCard2 : '+tCard2.size());
    system.debug('*********************tCard2 : '+tCard2);

for(Timecard_Entries__c t: tCard)
    {
            if(t.Invoice_Generated__c!=TRUE){
            if(i<tCard.size())
        {
            TotalBillableHours += t.Hours__c;
            i++;

    system.debug('*********************Total Billable Hours : '+TotalBillableHours ); 
        system.debug('*********************Startsheet(Project) Name : '+t.Project_ID__c); 
    }
    } 
    }

for(Resource_Bill_Rate__c rsc:trigger.new)
        {
            rsc.Total_Billable_Hours__c = TotalBillableHours;
        }
    system.debug('*********************Total Billable Hours : '+TotalBillableHours); 

}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may have your test annotated with `@isTest(SeeAllData=true)` and in the org you are deploying to there are a large number of rows. Fixing the test is one thing, but you also need to make sure your trigger works (uses a selective enough query) with large numbers of rows. I suggest you post the trigger and test source code if you need more help.

Comment: I agree with Keith, we need to see your code. I've block quoted error messages related to a non-selective query that clearly needs addressed in your code as it appears as though ti could be a significant part of your problem. It also appears as though your test code data being generated isn't satisfying your org's validation rules when being inserted as test data. You'll need to determine what what that criteria is to satisfy the validation rules.

Comment: @Summit Please dont disclose Usernames while posting questions

Comment: I agree with Keith, we need to see the code and once again you also check your test code or apex code because by seeing above error message your test class code or apex code is not satisfying the production environment also see any workflows or validations are causing errors

Comment: Based on the code you've posted it looks like the test setup in testResourceBillRate is causing some code that is in or called from a trigger (`trg_CalculateHours`) to fail. So effectively your testResourceBillRate class is exposing a bug in that trigger code. Using `@isTest(seeAllData = true)` is generally a bad idea so simply removing that from testResourceBillRate may make that test work. But there is still the serious problem in `trg_CalculateHours` that needs addressing of its query failing with large volumes of data. See @crmprogdev's suggestions about the other test failures too.

Comment: @KeithC  
You said I should not use @isTest(seeAllData = true). Please suggest what should I use. If I remove @isTest(seeAllData) then it will fail the class. Please suggest.

Comment: @SumitMattey OK then starting by fixing the problem in `trg_CalculateHours` might make more sense so you can leave the `@isTest(seeAllData = true)` in place for now. You can then later work to remove the `@isTest(seeAllData = true)` from your tests as that usually results in cleaner and less environment (org sensitive) tests.

Comment: @KeithC After your suggestions I saw my CalculateHours code and found no issues as such. Please confirm.

Answer (score 1):

On the:

> Trigger.trg_CalculateHours: line 37, column 1: []
>   testResourceBillRate.myUnitTest1 System.DmlException: Update failed.
>   First exception on row 0 with id a0I9000000FllpDEAR; first error:
>   CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, trg_CalculateHours: execution of
>   BeforeUpdate
>
> caused by: System.QueryException: Non-selective query against large
>   object type (more than 100000 rows). Consider an indexed filter or
>   contact salesforce.com about custom indexing. Even if a field is
>   indexed a filter might still not be selective when: 1. The filter
>   value includes null (for instance binding with a list that contains
>   null) 2. Data skew exists whereby the number of matching rows is very
>   large (for instance, filtering for a particular foreign key value that
>   occurs many times)

error, line 37 of the trigger code you posted is just after these queries:

```
tCard = [SELECT Hours__c,Project_ID__c, Invoice_Generated__c, TimeCard__c FROM Timecard_Entries__c WHERE Project_ID__c
        =:ProjectID and Date__c >=:pFrom and Date__c <=:pTo];
tCard2 = [SELECT Hours__c,Project_ID__c, Invoice_Generated__c, TimeCard__c FROM Timecard_Entries__c ];
```

The second one appears to be there for debugging purposes only and could certainly cause the error you see as it has no "where" clause at all. So start by removing that.

If the error is still happening it would be best to post the exact trigger source and the exact error message (so the line number points to the right query) and ask for advice on how to fix.

(By the way, this sort of summing can be done with less Apex code looping by using a SUM [aggregate query](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm) but the same issue of the where clause needing to be selective applies there too.)